# How can I group checkboxes in my custom ER widget?

Tags: 8, forms

I have created custom entity reference widget. Basically I need checkboxes inside my form element. But they have to be grouped by "Row" field presented on referenced entity type.

I'm not sure is it even possible to achieve that by extending core OptionsButtonsWidget, but here what I have now:

```
class MapCheckboxes extends OptionsButtonsWidget {

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/map-checkboxes';

    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);

    $options = $this->getOptions($items->getEntity());
    $selected = $this->getSelectedOptions($items);

    // If required and there is one single option, preselect it.
    if ($this->required && count($options) == 1) {
      reset($options);
      $selected = [key($options)];
    }

    if ($this->multiple) {
      $element += [
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#default_value' => $selected,
        '#options' => $options,
      ];
    }
    else {
      $element += [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#default_value' => $selected ? reset($selected) : NULL,
        '#options' => $options,
      ];
    }

    return $element;
}
}
```